# How to use filter over two different array inside a nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the count of the unique item from the array of objects. I have a dataset where I am having a array of objects inside that I am having a nested array of objects, I want to get the count of the two objects, I have taken the count of the one object based on the condition but I am unable to do the nested filter and get the count of the unique item. Could any one assist me what I need to achieve the same. Thanks in advance.

MockData:

```js
[
  {
    id: "123",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: { type: "in-progress" },
    subCatg: [
      {
        id: "A-1",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-01",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
      {
        id: "A-2",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-02",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "124",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: { type: "in-progress" },
    subCatg: [],
  },
];
```

In the above data, I need to get the count of object and nested array of object `subCatg`. I've added the logic to get the count of object but I am unable to get the count of `subcatg` I need the count of both.

Code:

```js
getCount = (itemstoBeCreated) => {
  const { typeCreated } = this.props; // props coming from anothe comp
  return (
    typeCreated + itemstoBeCreated.filter((items) => !items.inProcessing && isValidated === true).length
  );
};
```

I tried to get the count of `subCtg` with same condition but I am unable to get output.

Comment: what is your expected result from your mock data?

Comment: I need to get the length of the obj and subcatg array of obj length based on the condition: !items.inProcessing && isValidated === true

Comment: i fail to understand your code because it has nothing related to the mock data. in your code, if `itemstoBeCreated` is `subCatg`, then it has no problem.

Comment: itemstoBeCreated is the having the data coming from mockData

Comment: if `itemstoBeCreated` is `mockdata`, then try `itemstoBeCreated.subCatg.filter((items) => !items.inProcessing && isValidated === true).length`

Comment: mmm my current code will filter out the items inside the obj means it'will get the count of id:"123" and "124" but I need to get the count of "subCatg" if it is having value in it. And I need to get the count of both.

Comment: fist of all clear this concerns is value of inProcessing and isValidated bool or string , then is the condition you want is : inProcessing should be true or false and isvalidated should be true or false , then && of both should be true or false clear each one by one and you will get your solution

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking?

```js
const mockdata = [{
    id: "123",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: {
      type: "in-progress"
    },
    subCatg: [{
        id: "A-1",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-01",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
      {
        id: "A-2",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-02",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "124",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: {
      type: "in-progress"
    },
    subCatg: [],
  },
];

const result = mockdata.reduce((p, c) => p += c.subCatg.filter(cs => !cs.inProcessing && cs.isValidated === true).length, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: data has value in string so your solution will always return 0. let him clear basic concerns as I have added in main comment section.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = [
    {
        id: "123",
        type: "A",
        desc: "To be added",
        inProcessing: true, // hopping that you want bool value here 
        isValidated: false, // if its string then check your "Deciding Condition" to be equal with "true" or "false" as string
        status: { type: "in-progress" },
        subCatg: [
            {
                id: "A-1",
                status: {
                    type: "YTC",
                },
                type: "A-01",
                inProcessing: true,
                isValidated: false,
            },
            {
                id: "A-2",
                status: {
                    type: "YTC",
                },
                type: "A-02",
                inProcessing: true,
                isValidated: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "124",
        type: "A",
        desc: "To be added",
        inProcessing: true,
        isValidated: false,
        status: { type: "in-progress" },
        subCatg: [],
    },
];
let result=0 // make sure you place this variable before function as it stores count and start with 0
let count = (array) => {
    let subCount = array.filter((item,i) => {
        (item.subCatg && item.subCatg.length > 0) ? count(item.subCatg) : null;
        // return Write your "Deciding Condition"here after return true result of condition will be counted in result variable
        // For example
        //return (item.inProcessing && (item.isValidated===false)) //this will return 4 as result becouse inProcessing is true and checking isValidated===false returns true so true&&true gets true hence counted
        return (!item.inProcessing && item.isValidated)===false //this will return 4 as result becouse inprocess is true and !true is false and isValidated is false so false&&false will return true hence counted
        // make sure you apply your condition properly 
        // NOTE : I HAVE CONSIDER VALUE Of inProcessing and isValidated as typeof "bool" if you expect them to be string refer following condition
        // return (!item.inProcessing==='true' && item.isValidated==='false') this will return 4 as result. hope you get it
    }).length
    result+=subCount
}

count(x) // calling the function with your data as parameter
console.log(result) //your output
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly based on the question and the comments, you need the total count of objects filtered by the `inProcessing` and `isValidated` properties. So in the example data, that would match 2 objects.

If that's the case, you can achieve this pretty easily with a little recursion.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "123",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: { type: "in-progress" },
    subCatg: [
      {
        id: "A-1",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-01",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
      {
        id: "A-2",
        status: {
          type: "YTC",
        },
        type: "A-02",
        inProcessing: "true",
        isValidated: "false",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "124",
    type: "A",
    desc: "To be added",
    inProcessing: "true",
    isValidated: "false",
    status: { type: "in-progress" },
    subCatg: [],
  },
];

function recurseData(data) {
  let count = data.length;
  data.forEach(obj => {
    // strings are truthy values so we parse it to get the boolean. 
    const inProcessing = JSON.parse(obj.inProcessing);
    const isValidated = JSON.parse(obj.isValidated);
    const shouldCount = !inProcessing && isValidated && obj.subCatg;
    if (shouldCount) {
      count += recurseData(obj.subCatg);
    }
  })
  return count;
}
    

const count = recurseData(data);
console.log({ count });
```